# Different Color SVG (React Component) based on Width (TailWindCSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, components

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I have a content field which is purple before and white after the SM: tailwind value. This content has a button inside of it which contains an SVG. Now I want the SVG fill color to change based on the width, or either the background color which will be purple under 480px.

My SVG Component looks as following:

```
const ArrowUp = (props: JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width={12}
    height={12}
    fill="none"
    {...props}
  >
    <path
      fill={props.fill}
      d="m11.288 7.783-2.173.07.086-2.662.246-.904-.307-.139-.568.778L1.799 11.7.301 10.2l6.773-6.772.778-.568-.14-.308-.903.247-2.662.086.07-2.173 6.194-.2 1.078 1.077-.2 6.194Z"
    />
  </svg>
```

The arrow code is:

```
<ArrowUp fill="#3D00FF" className="group-hover:transform group-hover:rotate-45 group-hover:animate group-hover:duration-300 group-hover:ease-in-out inline-block mr-2 ml-2 relative bottom-0.5" />
```

I am wondering if there is a simple method of making the SVG component change fill color based on the tailwind 'sm:' attribute. And if not what would be cleanest way on achieving this?

Comment: Does this meet your requirement? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill

Comment: Oh wow, I never saw the links on the extended documentation. The solution was pretty simple I see: fill-[#243c5a] and sm:fill-[#243c5a]. Removing the fill prop and this did the trick. Should've watched it better! Thank you.